# How to specify kernel configuration in my custom linux kernel recipe

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto

I tried to write a custom Linux Kernel recipe for the latest stable kernel

```
DESCRIPTION = "Latest Stable Linux Kernel"
SECTION = "kernel"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/GPL-2.0;md5=801f80980d171dd6425610833a22dbe6"

inherit kernel

S = "${WORKDIR}/linux-5.6.15"

SRC_URI =  "https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.6.15.tar.xz;name=kernel" 

SRC_URI[kernel.md5sum] = "41f02b34dbb66ffa6b71bb3e2361e94d"
SRC_URI[kernel.sha256sum] = "65ab799393d490463c610270634874dfcb66440a312837d04b51bbb69323034e"
```

When i try to build this recipe, i thought it will fail at configuration stage, as there is no .config file provided.

Did i make any mistake? How to specify our configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

`kernel.bbclass` contains following information in its do_configure task:

```
# Copy defconfig to .config if .config does not exist. This allows
# recipes to manage the .config themselves in do_configure_prepend().
if [ -f "${WORKDIR}/defconfig" ] && [ ! -f "${B}/.config" ]; then
    cp "${WORKDIR}/defconfig" "${B}/.config"
fi
```

You need to include your own defconfig in `SRC_URI`.